# Argument 3 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in UnitOfWork.php on line 1060

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::__construct() must be of the
>   type array, null given, called in
>   /srv/mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on
>   line 1060 and defined

In controller

```
removeExpireProducts();
$em->flush();
```

Inside my service:

```
function removeExpireProducts()
{
    foreach ($products as $product) {
         $this->productRemover->removeProduct($product);
    }
}

productRemover class:
public function removeProduct(Product $product)
{

    $newOffer =
        $this->offerGroup
        ->createOffer($product);

    if (null !== $newOffer) {
        $this->em->persist($newOffer);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    $this->em->remove($product);
}
```

Comment: do you have same doctrine event listener on it?

Comment: @Matteo means same object of entity manager?

Comment: I mean [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) some services tagged as `doctrine.event_listener`

Comment: @Matteo I have not used any doctrine.event_listener its automatic throwing error.

Comment: Please include `productRemover` class and `removeProduct` method in your question. It's possible you unnecessary `flush()` going on Lifecycle Events

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski i have updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `flush()` to the bottom like this:

```
public function removeProduct(Product $product)
{
    $newOffer =
        $this->offerGroup
        ->createOffer($product);

    if (null !== $newOffer) {
        $this->em->persist($newOffer);
    }

    $this->em->remove($product);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

And in you controller remove `$em->flush();`

Than refactor your code to avoid executing `flush()` in this loop:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
     $this->productRemover->removeProduct($product);
}
```